# Struct in header file produces error in source file

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct defined inside `capi_utils.h` that looks like the following:

```
#ifndef _CAPI_UTILS_H_
# define _CAPI_UTILS_H_

...

struct ScalarVariable{
    char name[63];
    float value;
    uint8_T DataID;
    char type[50];
};

...
#endif
```

Inside of `capi_utils.c` I tried creating a variable to hold the struct like this

```
struct ScalarVariable sVariable;
```

Which only produces an error when I try setting a value inside the struct like this:

```
sVariable.name = paramName;
```

Error message is:

```
capi_utils.c:27: error: invalid use of undefined type `struct ScalarVariable'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

I just had to include `capi_utils.h`. Didn't think I had to because I had understood source files and headers different for some reason.

**EDIT 2:**

To clarify, I even got errors when trying to set DataID, not only the array.

```
void GetValueFromAdress(const char_T*  paramName,
                     void*          paramAddress,
                     uint8_T        slDataID,
                     unsigned short isComplex,
                     uint_T*        actualDims,
                     uint_T         numDims,
                     real_T         slope,
                     real_T         bias) {

sVariable.DataID = slDataID;

}
```

Would produce `error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct ScalarVariable'`

Comment: did you include `capi_utils.h` inside `capi_utils.c` ^^'

Comment: Also, the `name` field is an array.  So `sVariable.name = paramName;` is wrong.

Comment: What is the type of paramName ?

Comment: @Stargateur, Oh you have to do that? I thought they somehow were connected because it's a header for the source or something, heh.. Seems like it's working now though! Thanks :)

Comment: You can't assign arrays with `=`, simple as that. It has nothing to do with structs. Use strcpy.

Comment: Well, maybe that was a bad example from me @Lundin. Every other use also had errors, not just the array.

Comment: It will be quite hard to re-produce the error then.

Comment: First comment helped me fix it, but I can add some more @Lundin

Comment: As an aside, if `sizeof(float) == 4`, I wonder why you didn't make both member-arrays just one longer. It wouldn't change the structs layout, size or alignment any.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I'm very new to how C works, as you might have noticed. Why wouldn't changing the arrays one more effect anything? You mean the struct char arrays, correct?

Comment: @Kvixen: Well, the structs are generally (the standards guarantees are slightly looser) layed out such: 1. Alignment of struct is maximum of all members. 2. There is exactly enough padding inserted between members to satisfy the members alignment requirement. 3. The struct gets exactly enough trailing padding so it's a multiple of its alignment big. As a result, there is one padding byte after each of your member-arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cape_utlis.c`, you need to include the header file, like this:

```
#include cape_utlis.h
```

---

Moreover, change this:

```
sVariable.name = paramName;
```

to this:

```
strcpy(sVariable.name, paramName)
```

in order to copy the NULL-terminated string in C, you use the function [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/), and not the assignment operator.